# How does the computer recognise that a a given number is in its Two's comeplent form?

Tags: binary, computer-science, cpu-architecture, twos-complement

I understand what the Two's complement is and what it is useful for. What I'd like to know is how does the computer decide that the number is in its Two's complement form?

How and when does it decide that 1111 1110 is -2 and not 254? Is it at the OS level of processing?

Comment: If sign is of importance, there will typically be more than one CPU instruction to deal with either case (e.g. `MUL` vs `IMUL`  or `JA` vs `JG` on x86). For certain operations (like an addition) it is irrelevant if you intend to view those bits as -2 or 254; the result would be the same either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer will already be expecting the data to be in (or not in) two's complement form (otherwise there wouldn't be a way of telling if it is - 2 or 254). And yes, that would probably be decided at the OS-level.

You can probably relate this to the same kind of idea used when setting variable types when declaring variables in a high-level programming language; you'll more than likely set the type to be "decimal", for example, or "integer" and then the compiler will expect values to stick to this type.

Comment: so the CPU doesn't care if it's signed/unsigned; it will compute the requested operations (some instruction sent by the OS) on the received bits and the OS will interpret the bits returned. Am I correct here?

Comment: I don't see what the OS has to do with this. At the CPU level you've got different instructions (or different variants of the same instruction) for when you want the operands to be treated as signed vs unsigned - for those operation where signedness matters (for more operations it doesn't). If you're programming in a higher-level language than assembly language you've typically got signed and unsigned data types, and the compiler will select the appropriate instructions based on that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I think it is dependable on programming language.

Lets say integer allocates 1 byte of memory (to make it simple).

If it is UNSIGNED integer (only positive numbers) you can use any number from 0 to 255 (in total of 2^8 numbers, zero included).

00000000 would be 0, and
11111111 would be 255 decimal.

But if your integer is SIGNED ( u can use both, negative and positive numbers) you can use values from -127 to 127, zero included (again 2^8 numbers).

If your compiler bumps into 11111111 SIGNED int value, it will not interpret it as 255 because signed int allows only values from 0 to 127 for positive numbers so it will take it as -1. Next one, -2 would be 11111110 (254 decimal) and so on...